# Recreating ASP.NET MVC website from source files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

my client has had his website developed in ASP.NET C#. Since then the developer closed down and now he needs to re-host his website on different server.
The website is split into two parts: admin panel and main pages. each folder contains bin, Views, Assets subfolders, web.config files and Global.asax file. The website uses Entity Framework but there are no database files whatsoever and web.config files need  to be added. Is it possible to somehow reverse engineer the source code to create needed databases along with all the required tables?

Comment: _Source code_? or compiled assemblies?

Comment: Didn't the contract with the former dev say anything about intellectual property of source code?

Comment: So you're asking how to recreate the database along with its contents based on some existing binaries you have of an old website? I say: good luck with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it can be a daunting task, you can decompile .net binaries with the following tool: http://ilspy.net/

If EntityFramework code first was used, you can restore the database using entity framework migrations. See the last part of this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks! that actually worked. I've extracted custom binaries and they had all the code first information needed along with .csdl .msl and .ssdl files. Now to get it all work..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ilspy I'd recommend looking at JetBrains [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).  I've used it to recover source code for a couple of my projects from back before I was using a proper source control.

One thing to be aware of when using a decompiler is that you're going to get the actual code produced, not the original source.  The things that we call 'syntactic sugar' will look completely different when decompiled.  Some of them might come out so mangled that you won't get them to compile.